# Recursion method that finds the sum between two numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, sum, recursive-datastructures

I want to implement a recursive method that finds the sum of x consecutive integers, starting from a starting number and ending with an end number.

For example, if start = 0 and end = 3, the method returns 6 (0+1+2+3). I tried to come up with the right code but I'm new to recursion and I couldn't find the right base case.

```
public static int summation(int start, int end) {
        if (start == end) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return  summation(end, end - 1);
        }
}
```

Comment: As you are summing numbers, your recursive case will need to add a number to the result of the recursive call. Also, does it look correct to you that `start` is unused in the recursive case? I suggest that you either run through your code on paper, or use the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

This works but make sure that start is less than end.

```java
public static int summation(int start, int end) {
    if(start < end) return start + summation(start + 1, end);
    else return end;
}
```

If you want to use the method to calculate sum between start and end even if start > end, then use this code:

```java
public static int summation(int start, int end) {
    if(start < end) return start + summation(start + 1, end);
    else if(start > end) {
        start += end;
        end = start - end;
        start -= end;
        return summation(start, end);
    }
    else return end;
}
```

If recursion is not compulsory, you can use the formula for sum of Arithmetic Progression which you learn in HighSchool Algebra.

Formula for Sum of an AP is 
`S = n/2 * (2a + (n-1) * d)`

In your case as you have to find the sum of consequetive terms, this formula simplifies to: 
`S = n/2 * (2a + n -1 )`

Here, `a` is the starting term and `n` is the x consequetive integers from start to end.

```java
public long sum(int start, int end) {
    int n = end - start + 1;
    return n/2 * (2L * start + n - 1);
}
```

Works even if `start` and `end` are negative. Just make sure `start` < `end`.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is a terrible approach here. Let's apply the method [Gauss](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/qq/database/qq.02.06/jo1.html) used in elementary school, the sum of the numbers `1` to `n` is found by taking of half of `n` multiplied by `n + 1`. Like,

```
private static long sumN(int n) {
    return ((1L + n) * n) / 2;
}
```

Then you can use that to find `summation` like

```
private static long summation(int start, int end) {
    return sumN(end) - sumN(start);
}
```

No recursion (or iteration) required.

Comment: This won't be correct if the range includes negative numbers.